# iOS. Make a layout constraint to glue to status bar bottom + X regardless of navigation bar

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I have a bunch of view controllers with slightly different layouts but with the same requirement for a vertical position of a top UILabel. It has always be X(=70) units from status bar. These view controllers might be added to navigation controllers with navigation bars or not.

How can I make a relatively generic layout constraint to account for navigation bar so my title is always X units from status bar regardless if the view controller is in navigation stack or not?

(I know that I can change constants for existing constraints in runtime, but this might be a bit problematic with a lot of controllers with xibs. I am looking for something more generic preferably in interface builder)

I am using iOS 11 SDK with Safe Area guides.

Please see pictures for more clarity.

1. Status bar only with X units to status bar. There is a constraint to top of Safe Area with constant X.

[image: 1.Status bar only]

2. Status bar + navigation bar. There is again a constraint to top of Safe Area but this time to get the result I wanted, I had to subtract navbar.height from X. constant X - navbar.height.

[image: 2. Status bar + navigation bar]

Basically I look for something that will allow to automatically adjust constant of constraint depending on presence of navigation bar. Maybe there is a possibility to achieve this with a couple of constraints which are "easily" copiable from xib to xib.

Answer (score 2):

If setting it in code is an option for you, you can use this simple hack:

```
topLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height + 70).isActive = true
```

So basically you constrain it to top of the view (skipping the topLayoutGuide and safe area guides) to the constant plus the height of the status bar.

Note that if you allow landscape mode, or there are views were the status bar is hidden, you would have to add more code to handle those cases.

Comment: Is self.view.topAnchor the topmost point of the window? According to Apple docs : `Use this anchor to create constraints with the view’s top edge.` I would assume that view's top edge is not the same as window's top edge. Hmm, good question is also if I could do `.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.window!.topAnchor, ...`

Comment: @iur if the answer was helpful, can you please accept it?

Comment: it was useful, and I have up-voted it, but it doesn't answer the question unfortunately, so I cannot accept it as correct.